# Sort data based on checkbox

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have three columns with multiple rows: The first column (A)is numbered (1,2,3,4) the second column(B) is lettered (A,B,C,D), and the third is corresponding info (C).

I want to be able to select a boolean that toggles the sorting of the sheet between sorting in descending order by the numbers (Column A) and sorting by the letters (Column B)

Thank you!

[image: An image for clarification]

Comment: Got confused. So what would the expected result be? And where is the checkbox you mention? Please share a test sheet or a table.

Comment: Added an image, thank you. So basically, the checkbox would reorder the set to be by numbers. Currently it's sorted by letters.

Answer (score 0):

**Try:**

```
=IF(D1,SORT(A4:C,1,false),ARRAYFORMULA(A4:C))
```

**Result:**[image]

Using `IF()` to check if checkbox is true, then `SORT()` the Columns A,B,C by descending order based on column A.

Comment: Let me know if this works for you or you have other questions, feel free to ask.

Comment: Thank you so much, especially for the helpful gif. My only remaining question is if it's possible to apply this to the original data itself, instead of generating a separate set. (If you're interested, this is for film production: On set, I want to switch between viewing the shot-list in shooting order and narrative order, but I still want to be able to edit the data on that same sheet no matter what order it happens to be in)

Comment: @Emil Hi, it is not possible using just formula since you will need to reference the original data. It is possible using apps script. Do you need help setting it up?

Comment: As a general rule in StackOverflow, if your concern is solved please accept an answer which works best for you. This is to let other members from the community with the same concern as yours know that the issue resolved. [How to accept an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). If it does not exactly answer your question but somehow helped in any way, upvotes are highly appreciated.